# Counterexample to a variation on "The politician theorem".

Tags: graph-theory, examples-counterexamples

The following is a theorem in graph theory that has a nice 'real world' interpretation:

> Suppose $G$ is a finite simple graph in which any two vertices have **precisely** one common neighbour. Then there is a vertex adjacent to all other vertices.

The word "precisely" is necessary here; if we replace it by "at least" then the statement is false.

My question is: What is the smallest counterexample to this false statement? I've found this one:
[image]

I've convinced myself that this is indeed the smallest counterexample, but my "proof" is very cumbersome and ugly. It is barely anything more than checking all smaller graphs. Then again I know practically no graph theory. Is there an elegant way to prove this is the smallest counterexample, if it is that?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $G$ is a graph in which any two vertices have at least one common neighbour, but no vertex is adjacent to all other vertices.  Let $a$ be a vertex, $b$ a vertex not adjacent to $a$, and $c$ a vertex adjacent to both $a$ and $b$.  By assumption, there is a vertex $d$ not adjacent to $c$ (and this can't be $a$ or $b$).  A common neighbour to $a$ and $d$ can't be $b$ or $c$, so it is a new vertex $e$.  That's $5$ vertices already.  If we had a smaller counterexample than yours (in terms of number of vertices), it would need $5$ vertices, so we can't afford any new vertices.  Now $b$ and $d$ need a common neighbour, which can only be $e$.  Since $e$ can't be adjacent to everything, it can't be adjacent to $c$.  But then $a$ and $c$ have no common neighbour.